# Maven issue while creating Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: maven, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to create Jenkins Pipeline for one of my automation job. I created Jenkins file. Code specified below:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    def mvn_version = 'MavenTest'
    withEnv( ["PATH+MAVEN=${tool mvn_version}/bin"] ) {
      //sh "mvn clean package"
    }

    stages {
        stage('Git checkout') { // for display purposes
            steps {
                git branch: "ReportTest", url: 'https://github.abc.com/vsing136/testWDM.git'
                 sh "mvn clean verify"
            }
        }

        stage('Stage 1') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello world!' 
            }
        }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
emailext body: "Build URL: ${BUILD_URL}",
        subject: "$currentBuild.currentResult-$JOB_NAME",
        to: 'vabc1@example.com'        

    }
}
```

Screenshot with my job configuration specified below:

[image]

I am not sure what am I doing wrong but I am getting error for this configuration -

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 4: Tool type "maven" does not have an install of "Maven 3.3.9" configured - did you mean "Maven"? @ line 4, column 11.
       maven 'Maven 3.3.9'
             ^

1 error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code worked for me:

```
agent any
    tools {
    maven 'MavenTest'
  }
```